# convert VBA to vb.net

Tags: vba, vb.net

I am migrating my application from VBA to VB.

I am writing my code from scratch. I have a piece of code in VBA which uses dictionary. Can someone help me how to convert this in VB. I am unable to do so.

Also is there any easy way to convert VBA code to VB rather than writing it from scratch.

Many thanks.

Code:

```
public FunctionCalldctionary()
    Dim  myDict As Dictionary
    SetMyDictionary pDict
End Function

Private Sub SetMyDictionary (tempDict As Dictionary)
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim i As Long, numAs Long

    Set inDict = New Dictionary

    ' Loop through each entry in the list, adding to the dictionary
    numcosts = 0
    For i = 1 To 12
        If v(i, 1) <> "" Then
            numAs = numAs + 1
            inDict.Add v(i, 1), numAs 
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I am not sure how to declare and use this dictionary in VB.

Comment: `from VBA to VB` - is it VB.NET with which you've tagged the question, or in fact VB6?

Comment: Hi it is vb.net Have edited the question as well

Comment: VBA does not have a native Dictionary object.  It is  an object that becomes available when you add a reference to the Scripting runtime.  Dictionaries are then declared as scripting.dictionary.  If you are using Word as the host for your VBA then you will also encounter the Word dictionary object which is dictionary of word spellings.  Before you try to convert VBA to VB you should first ensure that you use Option Explicit in each of your modules and address all the errors indicated.  You should then install rubber duck and do a code inspection and address all the issues raised.

Comment: Once you have followed the route above you will be in a good position to transfer your VBA code to a VB module in Visual Studio Community edition.  This will raise a host more issues but at least these will now be just due to language differences rather than incorrect code.  This is a good route to follow as you will learn a lot.  The intellisense in Visual Studio is much more extensive than in VBA.  You will also need to use F1 (both VBA and VB)  to pull up help the MS help pages for keywords.  Good luck on your journey.

Answer (score 0):

VB.NET is much more [strongly typed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_and_weak_typing) than VBA.

hence, `Dictionary` in VB.NET must be set with the data type of the key and the value.

 note that keys must be unique values.

here is a little example:

```
Sub Main()

   ' key and value data types (of T) must be passed as parameters to the dictionary constructor '
    Dim myDict As New Dictionary(Of Int16, Long)

    ' add to dictionary
    For i = 1 To 20
        myDict.Add(i, 7)
    Next

    ' populate all KeyValuePairs from dictionary '
    For Each itm As KeyValuePair(Of Int16, Long) In myDict
        Console.WriteLine("Key: {0} Value: {1}", itm.Key, itm.Value)
    Next

    ' find value by key '
    Console.WriteLine("value of key that has a value of 2: {0}", myDict(2))

End Sub
```

As for your second question, behind the scenes VBA and VB.NET are two completely different languages. 
despite the fact that they share some similarity in syntax they compile / interpreted **absolutely** different, hence **conversion must be made by the programmer** and without some automatic tool (and as far as i know there is no such one, and even if exist I would not trust it`s quality). 
furthermore, 
VB.NET is running on the [.NET framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) and translated to [MCIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language)
compered to VBA that compiles to [P-Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-code_machine):

*From Wikipedia:*

> Code written in VBA is compiled to Microsoft P-Code (packed code), a proprietary intermediate
>   language, which the host applications (Access, Excel, Word, Outlook,
>   and PowerPoint) store as a separate stream in COM Structured Storage
>   files...

Comment: Thanks I'll try the same.

Answer (score 0):

Comments and explanations in-line.

```
'Functions in vb.net must has a return datatype and include Return statement
'Subs are called SetMyDictionary(pDict)
'Since the Dictionary passed to SetMyDictionary is never used 
'I remmed out the entire Function
'Public Function Calldctionary()
'    Dim myDict As Dictionary
'    SetMyDictionary pDict
'End Function

Private Sub SetMyDictionary()
    'Guessed that v was a 2 dimentional array because elements were referenced as v(i,1)
    'Guessed at size of array
    'Guessed that it was String because it was being compared to ""
    Dim v(11, 1) As String
    'must be integer to use in For loop
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim numAs As Long

    Dim inDict As New Dictionary(Of String, Long)

    ' Loop through each entry in the list, adding to the dictionary
    'What list?
    For i = 1 To 12
        'makes no sense since v is empty
        If v(i, 1) <> "" Then
            'If you are only looping 12 times why is numAS a Long?
            numAs = numAs + 1
            inDict.Add(v(i, 1), numAs)
        End If
    Next i
    'Everything falls out of scope here so I am not sure what is accomplished.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I had some success with https://converter.telerik.com.

It is important to keep one's expectations low.

First, note that this tool converts VB.Net (and not VBA) to C# and vice-versa, but it handles VBA, well, rather valiantly.  At the very least, you should have no option statements, option explicit should have been used, and ptrsafe api functions would probably need to be excised.  Also if you have forms and the like, that code would need to be dealt with as well.  There is no 100% conversion, depending on the code, maybe 30%, but at the very least some of the mind-numbingly soul-crushing tedious things like updated declarations may have been done for you.

Also check your resulting code very carefully.  1-based arrays may be returned from the various Office object models which of course will not be taken into consideration.

Using this is far better than just copy pasting the code from VBA then going through all of the errors by hand.